# Android MediaRecorder Exception when stopped

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am creating an app that records phone calls, both incoming and outgoing. The recording should stop when call ends.But I get an **Illegal State Exception**.Th exception is at `mediarecorder.stop()`.**"Stop called between invalid state 4"**.I have no idea what that means.This is the first time I am using MediaRecorder. I have checked similar questions..but their answers did not help me.Your help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance..This question [Error on MediaRecorder Stop : stop called in invalid state 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041225/error-on-mediarecorder-stop-stop-called-in-invalid-state-4) did not help me as the problem in that question was the user called **prepare()** before he called the **stop()** method. It is not similar to my case.

**Code:**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private Context context;
    boolean isRinging=false;
    String filepath;
    String internalfilename="AUD";


    public TeleListener(Context context,String filepath) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filepath=filepath;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        MediaRecorder mediaRecorder= new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filepath+internalfilename);
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                if (isRinging) {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    mediaRecorder.reset();
                    mediaRecorder.release();
                    isRinging=false;
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Idle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                isRinging=false;
                Toast.makeText(context, "Offhook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isRinging=true;
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4
03-E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:967)
at TeleListener.onCallStateChanged(TeleListener.java:43)
at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage
(PhoneStateListener.java:323)                                                                                            
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on MediaRecorder Stop : stop called in invalid state 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041225/error-on-mediarecorder-stop-stop-called-in-invalid-state-4)

Comment: Keep `MediaRecorder` instance globally.

Comment: Shalu..I am trying it now

Comment: Nope that didnt help

Comment: Maciej..The permission have been declared in the Manifest as well as in the MainActivity.java

Answer (score -2):

```
private void stopRecording() {
if (null != recorder){
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
```

You should not be calling **prepare** when you're stopping the **MediaRecorder**. The **prepare** method is something you call prior to starting the recorder. Refer to the state diagram in the **MediaRecorder** documentation.

Comment: You just copied the answer from another question and pasted it here

Comment: I am not calling prepare before stop

Comment: This is not the answer for the question as Jobin is not going through this scenario.