# Android MediaRecorder not working in some devices

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I am running Media Recorder in background service which is running perfect in Samsung 6.0 and above devices, but it is not working in lower devices. Throwing the below exception

```java
stop called in an invalid state: 4

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.shoaibnwar.crighter, PID: 28547
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:946)
    at com.shoaibnwar.crighter.Services.RecordingAudio.stopRecording(RecordingAudio.java:114)
    at com.shoaibnwar.crighter.Services.RecordingAudio.access$000(RecordingAudio.java:24)
    at com.shoaibnwar.crighter.Services.RecordingAudio$1.run(RecordingAudio.java:69)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Here is my start recording code

```java
private void startRecording(File file) {

    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
    }
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    //mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_2_TS);
   // mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
    //mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

   /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000);
    } else {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
    }
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);*/
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("giftlist", "io problems while preparing [" +
                file.getAbsolutePath() + "]: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and stop recording function is

```
private void stopRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

i am setting the file path like bellow

```
private File getOutputFile() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS", Locale.US);

    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()
            +File.separator
            +Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC
            +File.separator
            + "/CRighterVoice/RECORDING_"
            + dateFormat.format(new Date())
            + ".m4a");


}
```

Comment: On these "lower" devices, is `mediaRecorder.start()` executing successfully, without throwing?

Comment: yes mediaRecorder.start it is running success like in 5.0 devices, but throwing exception when call stop function

Comment: Hmm... it could be permissions on the SD card, as described in [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041225/error-on-mediarecorder-stop-stop-called-in-invalid-state-4) comments. Try A.) testing using a file from inside the regular `getFilesDir()` or B.) make sure you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: it is problem in lollipop devices, in 6 or grater it is working find.

Comment: Could still be a file access issue. Maybe your path is wrong. Consider this: You're using `Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC` incorrectly; it's just the word "Music". To properly build a path to that location, you should use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. Maybe the path you formed just _happened_ to be correct on higher API levels.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issues. What I got from search is that basic problem is in
 `mediaRecorder.setAudioSource()` because you are using `AudioSource.MIC` so some device does not support this.

There are some Audio recording sources we can use while preparing the recording [doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource/), but sadly in each different device, it might be different.

For some devices, `VOICE_CALL` works, and for some, others. But at least we can try. So in my case, a device which is running Android below 6, `VOICE_CALL` is working fine.

Another reason is that **Sometimes prepare takes some time to complete**.  I've found this sample project [here](https://github.com/riul88/call-recorder-for-android/), which for some reason sleeps for 2 seconds on the UI thread between prepare and start calls of the `mediaRecorder`. It works fine.

Following is the link of the [project](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/PhoneCallRecorder/) that record call successfully you see and check how the media source is changed in all devices.

Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

before

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```